# What can I do about softened polyurethane finish?

Tags: wooden-furniture, polyurethane

I have a (bed) headboard that was refinished about 25 years ago.  The original finish was a white French Provincial.  The refinish consisted of white latex paint covered with a glaze. A protective top coat of oil based polyurethane was applied.

I frequently read in bed, so the back of my head contacts the headboard. That spot has become softened and sticky.  I've tried cleaning it with Fantastic, to no avail.

Can you offer any suggestions for me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your hair product or scalp oil has reacted with the poly finish.  I would take some mineral spirits or paint thinner and try to wipe the area vigorously to remove the softened poly and then lightly sand and recoat.  You should probably not rest your head there in the future, or put a pillow between your head and the board.